# Firefox and edge rendering mistake, or error. Need a fix

Tags: html, css, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am making website, and I want something like 7 `divs`, that are `75px` height and `width:100%;`. Now. In those divs, there are many other divs, but this is i think not valuable...

Now. It works great, in every browsers i tried, but mistakes were seen in Edge and firefox.. looks like the first two divs are great, but then, they are suddenly wrong (other divs[2-7]). It's VERY hard to explain, so better i'll give you some photos and [LINK](http://david.addagio.cz/gospel/aktualne.html) to the website, so you can see it and understand.. (NoTE! i have two monitors, each with different size, so the photos are bit weird ;))

[image]

Now, you can see this "item menu" at the bottom of the page, just start scrolling...

for sure, there is css (might help):

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight:100;
    color:#666666;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#full_1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.item{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #464646;
}

    .item_roll{
        height: 275px;
    }
    
.box_rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
         transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.box_transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
    
#date{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#info{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    display:none;
}

#plus{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    padding: 22.5px;
}
    
h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding:24px 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#date h1{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="item" style="border-left: 4px solid #8E44AD;">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div id="date">
            <h1>31. 5.</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <h1>Velikonoční koncert | Přerov | Kulturní dům Rubín</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="plus">
            <img class="plus_x" src="plus.png" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a quick fix, try adding `display: block; float: left; clear: both;` to your outer 7 divs.

Comment: @Lewis kinda works, but it totally kills javascript..

Comment: What do you mean, 'but it totally kills javascript'?

Comment: javascript didn't work... don't know why, but now, after repetly load it to the servers, it works.. so.. thanks a lot man! :)

Comment: Not really seeing the problem in the snippet you gave (unless the problem was the missing `</div>` I had to add). However, you probably need the clears on `.item`, since without it, turning off the `display:none;` causes everything to wig out pretty badly. Telling the browser a `div` is `display:block;` is redundant unless you "reset" `div` off of `block` for some ungodly reason. As for JS having stopped working temporarily... Always make sure you saved, and double tap `F5` to reload bypassing cache. Sometimes that's the issue =P

Comment: everyone has this issue. so open the developer tools for the browsers that have an issue and work from there. you may even need some javascript to check which browser you are using and target specific css for each one of those that has problems. In other words just having one complete css file may not do the trick